# Row Index out of range exception while selecting a row where i removed

Tags: java, swing, jtable, row

```
int[] selRows = getNstInclude().getTable().getSelectedRows();

if (selRows.length == 0) 
{
return;
}

int selIndices = getNstInclude().getTable().getSelectedRow();
for (int i = selRows.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
getNstInclude().getTableModel().removeRow(selRows[i]);
}

getNstInclude().getTable().setRowSelectionInterval(selIndices, selIndices);
```

where getNstInclude() is my jtable.

in the above code,intaially iam removing a row from my jtable and then iam selecting a row by using  a same index where i removed the row,But it showing row index out of range exception.
 can someone help me that what i done a mistake here?
thanks in advance

Comment: @Mike de Klerk you basically get the issue, undelete and add test if selRows.length >0 before loop

Comment: @irrelephant [2nd. code example in the API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html)

Comment: @mKorbel Ok, so the problem is `selIndices` being -1 in the `setRowSelectionInterval`? Edit - wait, that's an `IllegalArgumentException`.

Comment: this was reason to my comment (@Mike de Klerk post correct answer and delete it, and users with rep >10k see deleted post everywhere), but without testing `if (selRows.length) then can to delete rows is reverse order`, I can to post answer about if you have got any issue about

Comment: hmm .. you did remove all selected rows including the selIndices (which is the first in array), so if the selection had been from selIndices to the end of the table ... :-) Hard to tell, of course, without SSCCE